# Implement same methods in different classes

Tags: python, class, methods, pygame, multiple-inheritance

I really don't know how to word this problem, so I'll try to explain it with an example.

Let's say I have three GUI classes:

1. Base Surface class
2. Detailed Surface Class
3. Sprite Class

All of them are independent of each other, no inheritance among them.
Now I have a function "drag()" that makes a surface/sprite dragable, and I want to implement this function as a method for all three of them.

Since it's the exact same code for all implementations I find it annoying, cumbersome and bad practice to rewrite the code.
The only thing I came up with so far was to make a saperate class for it and inherit this class. But that also doesn't seem to be the way to go.

I'd be very thankfull for some advice.

*EDIT*

Another example with a slightly different setup - I have the following classes:

1. BaseSurface
2. Dragable
3. Resizable
4. EventHandler

Only the first one is independent, the others depend on the first (must be inherited).
The end user should, without any effort, be able to choose between a simple BaseSurface, one with that implements dragable, one with resizable, one with eventHandler, and any combination. By "without any effort" I mean the end user should not have to make e custom Class and inherit the desired classes plus call the appropriate methods (**init**, update, ...) that some classes share.

So what I could do is make a class for every possible combination, eg.
 "BaseSurfaceDrag", "BaseSurfaceDragResize", ...
which will get messy really quickly. Whats a different and better approach to this?

Comment: Making a parent class and having the three classes inherit from it is exactly the way to go. This is an intended use of classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the kind of case that you should use a parent class for. In both cases it looks like your parent class (logically) should be something like:

```
class Drawable(object):
    def drag(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Drag and drop behavior"""
        # Your code goes here
```

Then each of your other classes inherits from that

```
class BaseSurface(Drawable):
    # stuff

class DetailedSurface(Drawable):
    # stuff

class Sprite(Drawable):
    # stuff
```

In the second case what you have are interfaces, so you could logically do something like:

```
class DragInterface(object):
    """Implements a `drag` method"""
    def drag(self):
        """Drag and drop behavior"""
        # Your code goes here

class ResizeInterface(object):
    """Implements a `resize` method"""
    def resize(self):
        """Drag and drop resize"""
        # Code

class EventHandlerInterface(object):
    """Handles events"""
    def handle(self, evt):
        # Code

class MyNewSurface(BaseSurface, DragInterface, ResizeInterface):
    """Draggable, resizeable surface"""
    # Implement here
```